# Dynamically change the firestoreConnect query

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to use pagination in my reservation app (React), where user can choose between building floors with pagination. I am using firestoreConnect to get data from firestore. The query looks like this

```
export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
    firestoreConnect([
        {
            collection: 'Building1',
            doc: 'Floor1',
            subcollections: [{ collection: 'Seats1' }],
            storeAs: 'Seats1',
            orderBy: ['order']

        },
        { collection: 'reservations' }
    ])
)(ReservDesk)
```

I am wondering if there is a possibility to dynamically change the collection name and the document name so if I click on page 2 than the first document changes from Floor1 to Floor2 and the subcollection changes from Seats1 to Seats2.

Answer (score 0):

You can map redux state into props for firebaseConnect through `mapStateToProps` which need to return the current doc and seat index along with any other state values.

Source: https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/issues/681#issuecomment-482843398

Comment: I added another connect to the code and now I can access the floors and the seats from the props. The problem is that event the query changes now, I don't get any reaction when I click on the next page.

Comment: This is how the code looks right now.
`export default compose(
    connect((state, props) => ({
        floorNumbertoProps: state.floorNumber
    })),
    firestoreConnect(props => [
        {
            collection: 'Building1',
            doc: props.floorNumbertoProps.floor,
            subcollections: [{ collection: props.floorNumbertoProps.seats}],
            storeAs: props.floorNumbertoProps.storeAs,
            orderBy: ['order']
        },
        { collection: 'reservations' }
    ]),
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
)(ReservDesk)`

Comment: this would be a new question, you can also highlight your code better and get a better diagnosis as this relates to how you are handling your redux state and cross-page behavior